# Can I remove default constructor? (0.8 ver)

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

I am using Solidity 0.8 version. If the contract does not require initialization in the constructor, I know that the default constructor is called(like `constructor () {}`), but can I remove this? Or do you recommend declaring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the constructor is an empty constructor you don't need to explicitly write it.

I don't also see any reason to include it for clarity purposes or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html#constructor

> If there is no constructor, the contract will assume the default constructor, which is equivalent to constructor() {}

Just be aware of your variables default values.